# When does objectify verify existing data in a related entity?

Tags: objectify

I am writing this out of my head now, so correct me if I'm wrong. But I think to remember that the following code verifies if the entity behind a Ref<> actually exists:

```
Ref<User> user; // we have a reference field to a user in another entity

public void referenceUser(Long userId) {
    Key<User> key = Key.create(User.class, userId); // this is protobuf as it looks, and no db access happens
    this.user = Ref.create(key); // this looks up if an existing record exists, and it fails if it does not, correct?
}
```

What happens if the Ref<> field is already set during an update? Is it correct that it is not verified again if the record still exists?

I would like to clarify when objectify ensures data integrity and when it does not cross-check if a referenced record exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objectify never ensures any kind of referential integrity. Neither does the low-level API.

Ref objects are just Key objects with a little more behavior (most importantly the get() method).